# How To Validate the html confirmation popups in Selenium

Tags: html, validation, selenium

How can we Validate the HTML popups in Selenium, i am just curious. I don't know any website to show you as an example below you can see the image, but at the time of the interview the company has given me a task to add the new record to their database and validate it, has it been added successfully  or not.

if the record get successfully added, two HTML confirmation pop-ups get open or else only one,They asked me to validate it.  In short, how to validate confirmation pop-ups:

[image]

Steps of the Task where like this:

1. Enter some Name and his designation
2. Validate: one Confirmation pop-up if record is already exists. Two confirmation popups if record successfully added.
3. if record exist try adding again until you succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Your pop-ups are CSS & HTML pop-up, not JavaScript/System Dialog.  So you can operate them as normal:  **find element -> operate element**

As you see, there can only one pop-up visible at a time. So inspect the pop-up find out a common locator which can find the 3 pop-ups.

And I guess the message in pop-up for recored exist and add success are different.
Implement Steps:

1. After click `Add` button
2. Use a driver.wait() function to wait pop-up appear 
   until the first pop-up come in 
   get message content inside pop-up 
   use message content as condition 
   if message not for record already exist, back and repear add again  
   else wait the second pop-up for record add success